# Cannot mount XFS partition

Tags: ubuntu, xfs

I have a XFS partition in one of my HDD partitions.

Here's my disks:

```
aksesfarma@elementary-PC:~$ sudo blkid -o list

device fs_type  label  mount point  UUID
-------------------------------------------

/dev/sda1  ext4  /                               xxxx
/dev/sda3  ntfs  System Reserved (not mounted)   xxxx
/dev/sda4  ntfs  (not mounted)                   xxxx
/dev/sda5  ext4  /home                           xxxx
/dev/sda6  swap  <swap>                          xxxx

/dev/sdb1  xfs   (not mounted)                   xxxx
/dev/sdb5  xfs   (not mounted)                   xxxx
/dev/sdb6  xfs   (not mounted)                   xxxx
```

Note here that `/dev/sda` is my main HDD (Linux/Windows dual boot) and works fine. The problem is in `/dev/sdb` or my second drive.

Here's after I mount `/dev/sdb1` to `/dev/sdb6` using command:

```
aksesfarma@elementary-PC:~$ sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdb1 /home/aksesfarma/drive1
aksesfarma@elementary-PC:~$ sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdb5 /home/aksesfarma/drive2
aksesfarma@elementary-PC:~$ sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdb6 /home/aksesfarma/drive3

aksesfarma@elementary-PC:~$ sudo blkid -o list
/dev/sdb1  xfs   /home/aksesfarma/drive1        xxxx
/dev/sdb5  xfs   /home/aksesfarma/drive2        xxxx
/dev/sdb6  xfs   (in use)                       xxxx
```

When I try the last command to mount `/dev/sdb6`, the cursor cannot receive input anymore. It just blinked. Note: the repeated `^C` is me, trying to cancel the command using Ctrl-C. No response and no output whatsoever.

[image]

Then I read an article about XFS-partition: [Here's the article](http://docs.cray.com/books/S-2377-22/html-S-2377-22/z1029470303.html)
Tried to enter this command `xfs_repair -n /dev/sdb6` or `xfs_check /dev/sdb6`

Still, Nothing happen, the partition still unmounted and my cursor still blinking

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal result if there is no error detected. (I run a check of a xfs-partition, in perfect condition, with the same result.)
Please provide more information about the mounting error or why your system cannot mount the partition, maybe this will shed some light on your problem.

Comment: right, before I get down-voted even more, here's the detail of my situation. Thank You